# What tools are needed for making wafer cookies?

Tags: equipment, cookies

I like to eat wafer cookies, such as the ones in the picture [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aWafers.jpg). These usually come in three flavors (chocolate, vanilla, and strawberry). Unlike regular cookies, which I can bake in the oven, and come out as round and thick, wafer cookies seem to be made of many layers and have a waffle-pattern on the outside. Unfortunately, cannot find any in the supermarket, so I want to make my own. Do I need any special machinery to create these cookies?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Google Images finds both normal cookies and normal filled hard waffles. Could you post a picture, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can use one these?

http://www.thecooksden.com/cuisinart-pizzelle-press-grill-brushed-stainless-nonstick-wm-pz2/

Buying one these might be little over the top:
http://hanshuangying.en.made-in-china.com/product/IoQnJEqGOOkC/China-Complete-Full-Automatic-Wafer-Press-Machine.html

[Pizelle maker at Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00006F2ME)